# C — #define calculates max value of size

Tags: c

In e2fsprog code base, there is one line such as:

```
#define NO_BLK ((blk64_t) -1)
```

and

```
  typedef __u64 __bitwise     blk64_t;
```

And I printf-ed this NO_BLK value, it is  18446744073709551615, which is 2<sup>64</sup>-1

My question is:
how does a parenthesis `()` turn a type `blk64_t` into a value 2<sup>64</sup>-1?

*Question closed.*

Comment: Don't you recognize type casting syntax?

Comment: thanks Barmar .got it. so stupid me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not what has happened here.

The `(blk64_t)` casts (converts) the value at it's right to the type `blk64_t`.

Here the value is -1. In 64-bit two's complement notation, signed integer `-1` and unsigned integer `2^64-1` has the same representation. 1111...111 (64 ones)